# Check if current date between two dates in french MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a collection of restaurant documents in my MongoDB database with an hours field having the format below.

How can I check if a restaurant is open now using MongoDB aggregation?

My hours field has data like this (with french days):

```
{
            "Lundi": [
                "08:00",
                "23:00"
            ],
            "Mardi": [
                "08:00",
                "23:00"
            ],
            "Mercredi": [
                "08:00",
                "23:00"
            ],
            "Jeudi": [
                "08:00",
                "23:00"
            ],
            "Vendredi": [
                "08:00",
                "23:00"
            ],
            "Samedi": [
                "08:00",
                "23:00"
            ],
            "Dimanche": [
                "08:00",
                "23:00"
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- uses the system variable `"$$NOW"` to get the current time of server
- converts each day open hours into a minutes range(to work on minutes also)
- `open = 01:00` `close = 02:30` limits=`[60,150]`
- if current hour is `01:30` then `min-now=90`
- and then filters `day=dayNow` `min-now` inside the `limits`
  (for example in our example case `90` is in the limit `[60,150]`)
- if at least 1 passed the filter store is open, else closed

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=69033367-m)

Query

```js
aggregate(
[{"$project":{"_id":0}},
 {"$project":
  {"open":
   {"$filter":
    {"input":
     {"$map":
      {"input":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"},
       "in":["$$this.k", "$$this.v"]}},
     "cond":
     {"$let":
      {"vars":
       {"info":
        {"day":{"$arrayElemAt":["$$r", 0]},
         "limits":
         [{"$add":
           [{"$multiply":
             [{"$toInt":
               {"$arrayElemAt":
                [{"$split":
                  [{"$arrayElemAt":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$$r", 1]}, 0]},
                   ":"]},
                 0]}},
              60]},
            {"$toInt":
             {"$arrayElemAt":
              [{"$split":
                [{"$arrayElemAt":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$$r", 1]}, 0]},
                 ":"]},
               1]}}]},
          {"$add":
           [{"$multiply":
             [{"$toInt":
               {"$arrayElemAt":
                [{"$split":
                  [{"$arrayElemAt":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$$r", 1]}, 1]},
                   ":"]},
                 0]}},
              60]},
            {"$toInt":
             {"$arrayElemAt":
              [{"$split":
                [{"$arrayElemAt":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$$r", 1]}, 1]},
                 ":"]},
               1]}}]}],
         "day-now":
         {"$arrayElemAt":
          [["Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi",
            "Samedi", "Dimanche"],
           {"$subtract":[{"$dayOfWeek":"$$NOW"}, 1]}]},
         "min-now":
         {"$add":
          [{"$multiply":[{"$hour":"$$NOW"}, 60]},
           {"$minute":"$$NOW"}]}}},
       "in":
       {"$and":
        [{"$eq":["$$info.day", "$$info.day-now"]},
         {"$gte":
          ["$$info.min-now", {"$arrayElemAt":["$$info.limits", 0]}]},
         {"$lte":
          ["$$info.min-now",
           {"$arrayElemAt":["$$info.limits", 1]}]}]}}},
     "as":"r"}}}},
 {"$project":{"open":{"$ne":["$open", []]}, "date-now":"$$NOW"}}])
```

Comment: The code does not show result as expected

Comment: Its ok now, its working, i thought those were restaurant names i dont know french.I re-wrote it for french-days.

Comment: How do you support timezones?

Comment: All those functions that i used have one more argument timezome.
[$hour](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/) etc 
I didn't added specific timezone, i should have added french time i guess.

Comment: Hey, what about end hour that are lower than start hour ? (example from 7 am to 1 am)

Comment: i dont think it will work if open hours are in 2 separate days. If you change your schema and add in each day like 4 opening hours for example  `"Mercredi": [ "00:00","02:00","08:00","23:00"]` it might work , but this query need change also.I think you should change your schema in general to make the quering easier

Answer (score 1):

Really an ugly data model. You have to translate french day names into number and the time values into `Date` objects. Then you can filter by day and times:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $unset: "_id" },
   {
      $project: {
         opening_times: {
            $map: {
               input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
               in: {
                  day: {
                     $switch: {
                        branches: [
                           { case: { $eq: ["Lundi", "$$this.k"] }, then: 1 },
                           { case: { $eq: ["Mardi", "$$this.k"] }, then: 2 },
                           { case: { $eq: ["Mercredi", "$$this.k"] }, then: 3 },
                           { case: { $eq: ["Jeudi", "$$this.k"] }, then: 4 },
                           { case: { $eq: ["Vendredi", "$$this.k"] }, then: 5 },
                           { case: { $eq: ["Samedi", "$$this.k"] }, then: 6 },
                           { case: { $eq: ["Dimanche", "$$this.k"] }, then: 7 }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  open: {
                     $dateFromParts: {
                        year: { $year: "$$NOW" }, month: { $month: "$$NOW" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$$NOW" },
                        hour: { $toInt: { $first: { $split: [{ $first: "$$this.v" }, ":"] } } },
                        minute: { $toInt: { $last: { $split: [{ $first: "$$this.v" }, ":"] } } },
                        timezone: "Europe/Paris"
                     }
                  },
                  close: {
                     $dateFromParts: {
                        year: { $year: "$$NOW" }, month: { $month: "$$NOW" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$$NOW" },
                        hour: { $toInt: { $first: { $split: [{ $last: "$$this.v" }, ":"] } } },
                        minute: { $toInt: { $last: { $split: [{ $last: "$$this.v" }, ":"] } } },
                        timezone: "Europe/Paris"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         open_today: {
            $first: {
               $filter: {
                  input: "$opening_times",
                  cond: { $eq: ["$$this.day", { $isoDayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }] }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         restaurant: {
            $cond: {
               if: {
                  $and: [
                     { $gte: ["$$NOW", "$open_today.open"] },
                     { $lt: ["$$NOW", "$open_today.close"] },
                  ]
               },
               then: "open",
               else: "close"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

See [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n9K-hmSDeI4)

Comment: Some dicts apparently contain data like this {"lundi": [], "mardi": [] ......} and this is causing this error when I run my pipeline using mongoengine *Failed to parse number 'Open24hours' in $convert with no onError value: Did not consume whole string*. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Depends on the result you like to get.